# Short story collection for young readers centred around ghosts and the weird

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, anthology-book

I'm trying to remember a short story collection centred around ghosts and the unexplained from my childhood. I read this book between the years of 1990 and 1995, so the publication date would not be after this time period.

I remember the first and last stories; the first was about a phantom racing car driver competing in a race with the protagonist, and the last was about two children who discover(?) a ship and go below deck to explore. When they return above deck, a lifetime (eg. 80 years) has passed despite them only experiencing the time passing as a couple of hours.

I remember a tagline for the book mentioning that the stories within become progressively more strange and weird.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you have any recollection of the cover art?  Was it hardcover or paperback?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I would be lying if I said I could give you a definitively correct answer to either of your questions. I _think_ the cover had a blue cover scheme (I can't remember the actual image unfortunately) and I _think_ it was in hardback.

Comment: It sounds like something by Paul Jennings, although I couldn't say definitely that he wrote the exact plots you've described.

Comment: Could it have been Goosebumps related?